# Gherkin: Is it correct to repeat steps?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am reading a lot about Gherkin, and I had already read that it was not good to repeat steps, and for this it is necessary to use the keyword "Background", but in the example of [this page](http://altom.ro/blog/writing-tests-with-bdd) they are repeating the same "Given" again and again, Could it be that I am doing wrong? I need to know your opinion about it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like with several things, this a topic that will generate different opinions. On this particular example I would have moved the "Given that I select the post" to the Background section as this seems to be a pre-requisite to all scenarios on this feature. Of course this would leave the scenarios in the feature without an actual Given section but those would be incorporated from the Background section on execution.

I have also seen cases where sometimes the decision of moving steps to the Background is a trade-off between having more or less feature files and how these are structured. For example, if there are 10 scenarios for a particular feature with a lot of similar steps between them - but there are 1 or 2 scenarios which do not require a particular step, then those 1 or 2 scenarios would have to moved into a new feature file in order to have the exact same steps on the Background section of the original feature.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is correct to keep the scenarios like this. From a tester's perspective, the Scenarios/Test cases should run independently, therefore, you can keep these tests separately for each functionality. 
But in case you are doing an integration testing, then some of these test cases can be merged, thus you can cover multiple test cases in one scenario.
And the "given" statement is repeating, therefore you can put that in the background, so you don't have to call it in each scenarios.

Note: These separate scenarios will be handy when you run the scripts separately with annotation tags, when you just have to check for a specific functionality, or a bug fix.